# Deploying Mezzanine on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, mezzanine

I've been following instructions from [this article](http://www.benhavilland.com/blog/deploying-mezzanine-on-heroku/) to deploy mezzanine on heroku 
I want to run static files from heroku so followed the instructions in the link as mentioned but I'm getting this error when I do "Heroku open"

```
Opening mezzanine-be... failed
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       Unable to find a browser command. If this is unexpected, Please rerun with environment variab
le LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true or the '-d' commandline option and file a bug at https://github.com/copiousfreetime/laun
chy/issues/new (Launchy::CommandNotFoundError)
    Backtrace:   /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/launchy-2.4.2/lib/launchy/applications/browser.rb:63:in `browse
r_cmdline'
                 /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/launchy-2.4.2/lib/launchy/applications/browser.rb:67:in `cmd_an
d_args'
                 /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/launchy-2.4.2/lib/launchy/applications/browser.rb:78:in `open'
                 /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/launchy-2.4.2/lib/launchy.rb:29:in `open'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:328:in `block in launchy'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:227:in `action'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:326:in `launchy'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/apps.rb:338:in `open'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:218:in `run'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
                 /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku open
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.4.1 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3
```

I got this log when I did "heroku logs"

```
2014-04-22T22:14:23.416063+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/c
onf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-04-22T22:14:23.472992+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-04-22T22:14:23.416081+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" %
tz)
2014-04-22T22:14:23.472983+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-04-22T22:14:25.275890+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-22T22:14:25.282406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-23T04:09:18.972452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-23T04:09:25.363685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py run_gunicorn -
b 0.0.0.0:55680 -w 1`
2014-04-23T04:09:26.682220+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" %
tz)
2014-04-23T04:09:26.682206+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/c
onf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-04-23T04:09:26.695461+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-04-23T04:09:26.695465+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-04-23T04:09:28.055144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-23T04:09:28.049204+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-23T09:52:14.401914+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-23T09:52:20.442477+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py run_gunicorn -
b 0.0.0.0:30095 -w 1`
2014-04-23T09:52:22.164719+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/c
onf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-04-23T09:52:22.164739+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" %
tz)
2014-04-23T09:52:22.179570+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-04-23T09:52:22.179578+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-04-23T09:52:23.715744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-23T09:52:23.701333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-23T16:07:31.408614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-23T16:07:38.553626+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py run_gunicorn -
b 0.0.0.0:56763 -w 1`
2014-04-23T16:07:41.125475+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" %
tz)
2014-04-23T16:07:41.238560+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-04-23T16:07:41.238566+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-04-23T16:07:41.125462+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/c
onf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-04-23T16:07:42.885219+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-23T16:07:42.896873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-23T22:09:39.404254+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-23T22:09:49.448643+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/c
onf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-04-23T22:09:49.460740+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-04-23T22:09:49.460747+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-04-23T22:09:49.448658+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" %
tz)
2014-04-23T22:09:48.480416+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py run_gunicorn -
b 0.0.0.0:9678 -w 1`
2014-04-23T22:09:50.717983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-23T22:09:50.696212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-24T04:11:51.194122+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-24T04:11:56.788844+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py run_gunicorn -
b 0.0.0.0:36892 -w 1`
2014-04-24T04:11:58.067181+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/c
onf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-04-24T04:11:58.067201+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" %
tz)
2014-04-24T04:11:58.092913+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-04-24T04:11:58.092919+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-04-24T04:11:59.280453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-24T04:11:59.295201+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-24T09:58:52.585546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-24T09:58:59.277649+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py run_gunicorn -
b 0.0.0.0:56234 -w 1`
2014-04-24T09:59:00.934694+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/c
onf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-04-24T09:59:00.934710+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" %
tz)
2014-04-24T09:59:00.951280+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-04-24T09:59:00.951287+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-04-24T09:59:02.627604+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-24T09:59:02.616971+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-24T13:30:08+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-04-24T13:30:44+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-04-24T13:30:44.581580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-24T13:30:44.310696+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by chetan.s.kaushal@gmail.com
2014-04-24T13:30:44.310620+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy da509c9 by chetan.s.kaushal@gmail.com
2014-04-24T13:30:51.209645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py run_gunicorn -
b 0.0.0.0:28107 -w 1`
2014-04-24T13:30:52.802204+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-04-24T13:30:52.802220+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-04-24T13:30:54.569234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-24T13:30:54.549885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-24T13:30:54.569652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-24T13:31:00.396574+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py run_gunicorn -
b 0.0.0.0:50627 -w 1`
2014-04-24T13:31:03.282440+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-04-24T13:31:03.282451+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-04-24T13:31:04.743794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-24T13:31:04.756855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-24T13:31:06.091140+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=m
ezzanine-be.herokuapp.com request_id=c1d2e607-a55c-422c-9ef1-f6a45ace8f82 fwd="1.23.88.93" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
2014-04-24T13:31:06.829718+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon
.ico host=mezzanine-be.herokuapp.com request_id=df6accba-7950-4bec-ae57-116ec3cfe5f6 fwd="1.23.88.93" dyno= co
nnect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-04-24T13:35:10+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-04-24T13:35:56+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-04-24T13:35:56.126982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-24T13:35:56.003342+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by chetan.s.kaushal@gmail.com
2014-04-24T13:35:56.003219+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8cdb5a0 by chetan.s.kaushal@gmail.com
2014-04-24T13:36:03.608314+00:00 app[web.1]: ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
2014-04-24T13:36:04.981170+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-24T13:36:02.181124+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.
0.0:59156 --noreload`
2014-04-24T13:36:04.967644+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-24T13:36:49.185541+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=m
ezzanine-be.herokuapp.com request_id=403daa9a-5359-4041-b0a0-a7ecaaf2a839 fwd="1.23.88.93" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
2014-04-24T13:36:49.802726+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon
.ico host=mezzanine-be.herokuapp.com request_id=d0a5e62e-29e4-444d-87f4-0a83f635a53c fwd="1.23.88.93" dyno= co
nnect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-04-24T13:38:54.744538+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createdb` by che
tan.s.kaushal@gmail.com
2014-04-24T13:39:02.543383+00:00 heroku[run.4712]: State changed from starting to up
2014-04-24T13:39:02.443450+00:00 heroku[run.4712]: Awaiting client
2014-04-24T13:39:02.480032+00:00 heroku[run.4712]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createdb`
2014-04-24T13:39:04.781382+00:00 heroku[run.4712]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-24T13:39:04.792816+00:00 heroku[run.4712]: State changed from up to complete
2014-04-24T13:39:35.844877+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createdb --noinp
ut` by chetan.s.kaushal@gmail.com
2014-04-24T13:39:43.296642+00:00 heroku[run.2213]: Awaiting client
2014-04-24T13:39:43.363388+00:00 heroku[run.2213]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createdb --
noinput`
2014-04-24T13:39:43.338269+00:00 heroku[run.2213]: State changed from starting to up
2014-04-24T13:39:45.504923+00:00 heroku[run.2213]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-24T13:39:45.513948+00:00 heroku[run.2213]: State changed from up to complete
2014-04-24T13:40:07.033895+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createdb` by che
tan.s.kaushal@gmail.com
2014-04-24T13:40:14.314579+00:00 heroku[run.5886]: Awaiting client
2014-04-24T13:40:14.359512+00:00 heroku[run.5886]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createdb`
2014-04-24T13:40:14.154217+00:00 heroku[run.5886]: State changed from starting to up
2014-04-24T13:40:16.102836+00:00 heroku[run.5886]: State changed from up to complete
2014-04-24T13:40:16.092128+00:00 heroku[run.5886]: Process exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three separate and unrealted issues here:

1. You can't run `heroku open` since it's failing to find a browser for some reason. Either way it's just a shortcut, you can open your heroku app directly in the browser.
2. Your application does not have `gunicorn` installed in the Django `INSTALLED_APPS`, add it and try again. (This is also explicitly mentioned in the link you mentioned.)
3. Your application is missing a required `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: I tried opening directly but it showed application error so I did "Heroku logs" I have gunicorn added in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: You also have an empty `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: yup what do I do about that. The settings says its provided by fabfile.py by default. I'm now adding a django application secret key

Comment: ok I added a key in fab file and committed to git and then pushed it to heroku. But again it shows same error and it shows unknown command for collectstatic, createdb and syncdb

Comment: @user2539745 you clearly have lots of issues with your deployment, I suggest you read up some more on what exactly you're trying to do before continuing.

Comment: I just want to deploy default mezzanine project which is running on my local pc to heroku

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements.txt must also have a gunicorn line.

```
pip install gunicorn
pip freeze > requirements.txt
git add requirements.txt
git commit -m "updated requirements"
git push heroku master
```

Try again with:

```
heroku open
```

I'm guessing you're missing other items in the requirements.txt too since you've run into this error but this will help you overcome gunicorn not being found.